# Constraints on the polar angle (θ) in the particle in a sphere problem

Tags: quantum-chemistry

For constraint in $\phi$,  $\psi(\phi+2\pi$)= $\psi(\phi$) seems logical as after 2$\pi$ rotation we go back to the same point, therefore functions should be same. But how does it hold for $\theta$ as rotation of $\pi$ gives diametrically opposite point on the sphere, why should then   $\psi(\theta+\pi$) be equal to $\psi(\theta$)?

Comment: Isn't it the same? If you add $2\pi$ to $\theta$, the value of the function is the same. Usually, this value goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, but the invariant still holds.

Comment: but we are adding $\pi$ to theta

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$, as far as I know. It's complicated by the fact that chemists usually use $\theta$ and $\phi$ a different way from the physicists, but I think OP is referring to $\theta$ as the angle made with the $z$-axis.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the *polar angle* measured as it were down from the north pole it ranges from $0..\pi$ and $\phi$ the azimuthal angle, (longitude round the equator) from $0..2\pi$.

Comment: There is no a priori restriction between the values of $\psi(\theta)$ and $\psi(\theta + \pi)$. Solutions of the particle-on-a-sphere problem are labeled by two indices $l$ and $m$, and solutions with even/odd $l$ satisfy $\psi(\theta) = \pm \psi(\theta + \pi)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, as [orthocresol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68771/constraints-on-the-polar-angle-%CE%B8-in-the-particle-in-a-sphere-problem#comment119688_68771) and [porphyrin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68771/constraints-on-the-polar-angle-%CE%B8-in-the-particle-in-a-sphere-problem#comment119786_68771) said, we should keep in mind that $\phi$ and $\theta$ must span different sets, and there are different conventions on them:

> Any spherical coordinate triplet (r, θ, φ) specifies a single point of three-dimensional space. On the other hand, every point has infinitely many equivalent spherical coordinates.
>
> [...]
>
> If it is necessary to define a unique set of spherical coordinates for each point, one must restrict their ranges. A common choice is:
>
> $r$ ≥ 0
>
> 0° ≤ $\theta$ ≤ 180° ($\pi$ rad)
>
> 0° ≤ $\phi$ < 360° ($2 \pi$ rad)

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Unique_coordinates))

In other words (using the convention above), you must have both $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = \psi(r, \theta, \phi + 2 \pi)$ and $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = \psi(r, \theta + 2 \pi, \phi)$ for spherical periodicity.
*This* is the basic symmetry on a sphere.

But the assignment $(r, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (x, y, z)$ becomes "ambiguous" (not injective) if the function is defined as an application from $[0, \infty) \times [0, 2 \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence *not invertible*.

You can easily see this if you imagine mapping the surface of earth by having a *very* long rope with its ends fixed at both poles (half diameter, 180°) and an airplane carrying the middle of this rope around the globe (full diameter, 360° movement).

That being said, the mapping $(r, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (x, y, z)$ must be taken from $[0, \infty) \times [0, \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But that does not mean that $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = \psi(r, \theta + \pi, \phi)$, and as [higgsss observed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68771/constraints-on-the-polar-angle-%CE%B8-in-the-particle-in-a-sphere-problem#comment119792_68771), $\psi(r, \theta + \pi, \phi)$ *is not necessarily equal to* $\psi(r, \theta, \phi)$.
But higgsss also observed that, for some problems, some solutions might have symmetries allowing $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = \pm \psi(r, \theta + \pi, \phi)$.

Solutions for the hydrogen atom are good examples of this: for the *minus* sign, *p* atomic orbitals, and, for the *plus* sign, *d* atomic orbitals.
You can see other orbital symmetries by looking at them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table).

Comment: You have it backwards. $\varphi\to\varphi+2\pi$ takes you to **the same** point on the sphere, so the value of $\psi$ must be the same. $\theta\to\theta+\pi$ takes you to **a different** point.

Comment: You're right, I edited and corrected the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: That's good, but now your answer is unrelated to the question, since the latter was about $\theta+\pi$.

Comment: I think it *is* still related to the question, since it addresses the fact that $\psi(\theta + \pi)$ is not necessarily equal to $\psi(\theta)$, as was asked, but I will rephrase it to make it more explicit.

Comment: I also further improved the answer. I hope it looks good now.

Comment: Yeah, now that's spot on.